# How can I add a background image in Stencil

Tags: css, bigcommerce

I have to upload a image through cyberduck to (`content/img/add-to-wish.png`) but the image can't be found. How can I fix this issue?

I am using `background: #fff url("../img/add-to-wish.png");`.

Comment: are you on stencil or blueprint?

Comment: I am in stencil.

Answer (score 1):

To call images inside your **webdav content folder in your SCSS files**, call them like so. *example webdav file structure content/img/filename.jpg*

```
background: #fff url("/content/img/filename.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

To call images from your projects **assets/scss files inside your SCSS files**, use the following structure.

```
background: #fff url("../img/filename.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

To call images inside your **theme's assets/img folder in your HTML files**, use the cdn handlebar helper below.

```
<img src="{{cdn 'img/filename.jpg'}}">
```

To call images inside your **webdav content folder in HTML files**, use the cdn helper with a webdav prefix. *webdav file structure content/img/filename.jpg*

```
<img src="{{cdn "webdav:img/image.jpg"}}">
```